# TOP 1 or LIMIT 1 not working in a Correlated Subquery - SPS 11

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to work on a query to fill the Price for a product where it is zero with non-zero value fro previous record. I tried to write a simple correlated subquery but its not working.

```
var_1 = select * from "XYZ"."PRD_TEST" where price <> 0 order by period desc;

var_out = select a.product,a.period, ( select price from :var_1 b where a.product = b.product and a.period > b.period and b.period <> 0 limit 1 ) as price from "XYZ"."PRD_TEST" a;

PRODUCT PERIOD PRICE
A 1 100
A 2 0 - to be filled with 100
A 3 0 - to be filled with 100
A 4 5
A 5 0 - to be filled with 5
```

I tried to replace the sub-query with scalar function but it does not take table as a Parameter.

I tried to achieve the output using Left outer join and Row_number but it's too expensive and runs for a long time.

I am looking for a best option to fetch only 1 record in the subquery just like TOP 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a scalar subquery like this ( select ... limit 1 is not considered scalar in HANA, unfortunately):

```
    Do begin

var_1 = select * from (( Select 'A' product, '1' period, '100' price from sys.dummy )
Union ( Select 'A' product, '2' period, '0' price from sys.dummy )
Union ( Select 'A' product, '3' period, '0' price from sys.dummy )
Union ( Select 'A' product, '4' period, '5' price from sys.dummy )
Union ( Select 'A' product, '5' period, '0' price from sys.dummy )) order by period desc;

var_out = ( select a.product,
             a.period, 
            ( select max(price) 
              from :var_1 b 
              where a.product = b.product 
              and a.period > b.period 
              and b.period <> 0 
              and b.period = ( select max(period) from :var_1 c 
                               where a.product = c.product
                                 AND a.period > c.period
                                 and c.period <> 0
                                 and c.price <> 0
              )) as price 
              from :var_1 a where price = '0' )
union (select product, period, price from :var_1 where price <> '0' );

select * from :var_out order by product, period;
end
```

Tested on sps12

Added after comment.
Why don't you just try? It is very simple.
Because I was curious I tried it on my HCP trial instance, takes about 1 sec for on milion rows. I included a ifnull to avoid rows with null-values where there is no price in earlier periods.

Here is the coding:

```
drop table var_1;
create column table var_1 as 
(
    select 
      cast ( 'Prod' || prd.GENERATED_PERIOD_START as nvarchar(20) ) product, 
      cast ( per.GENERATED_PERIOD_START as decimal(2)) period,
      cast ( case when rand() < '0.5' then rand() * '100' else '0' end 
             as decimal(5,2)) as price -- ~50% of price is 0
      from series_generate_integer(1,0,1000000/13) as prd,  --~1Mio records
           series_generate_integer(1,0,13) as per --12 periods + period 0 
);
merge delta of var_1;
select * from var_1
 order by product, period 
 limit 100;
do begin sequential execution -- don't let parallel execution influence the runtime-measurement
declare start_timestamp timestamp;
start_timestamp = current_timestamp;
var_out = ( select a.product,
             a.period, 
            ifnull ((select max(price) 
              from var_1 b 
              where a.product = b.product 
              and a.period > b.period 
              and b.period <> 0 
              and b.period = ( select max(period) from var_1 c 
                               where a.product = c.product
                                 AND a.period > c.period
                                 and c.period <> 0
                                 and c.price <> 0
              )),'0.0') as price 
              from var_1 a where price = '0' )
union (select product, period, price from var_1 where price <> '0' );

select nano100_between(:start_timestamp, (select current_timestamp from dummy) )/10000 as runtime_millisec from dummy;

select * from :var_out
 order by product, period 
 limit 100;
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Chris !! Just curious to know how would be the performance if there are more than a million entries in the VAR_1 temp table ? Will the nested sub-queries(please correct me if i called it wrong) create performance issue ?

Comment: @gokul: why didn't you just measure how good or bad performance is.? And what is good performance in your use case? Only out of curiosity I included coding to generate test data and measure execution time. 1sec per million records in HCP trial  is not that bad, right? Looking at Explain plan or plan wizard for the statement would be interesting, too. Maybe you can do this and add some value to the question. And, maybe one of the experts comes up with some faster solution using window function or other fancy stuff...

Comment: Hi Chris, I am working on the changes, I will definitely update the performance of the Query, Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: @gokul: If the answer was right and helped you, up voting or /and accepting my answer would be nice.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have voted up and accepted the answer. Thanks a lot for your help.